# AIX: How to find sftp file limit?

Tags: aix, sftp, ulimit

Can anybody please help to find sftp file limit on following version on AIX (7.1.2.3).

I have following values set I am not able sftp a 110 KB file.

```
ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         131072
stack(kbytes)        32768
memory(kbytes)       32768
coredump(blocks)     unlimited
nofiles(descriptors) unlimited
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited
memory(kbytes)       32768
```

I am interested in knowing: what is the memory limit and how does it affect the user?

Comment: You'll need more detail.  You have a source system (let's call it B) and a target system (let's call it A), we need to know which users on each side of the sftp connection, which direction you're moving the data, what the ulimits are on the target side for the user receiving the command, the command you're actually running and the specific error message or failure.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to sftp a file larger than 110KB? Do you get an error message? What exactly does the message say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a specific sftp file limit.  There are regular filesystem file limits, and limits imposed by ulimits, but they're not special to sftp.

So the answer is, sftp file transfers are limited by either the target filesystem limits, or the ulimits set for the user in question.

Given modern AIX filesystems have very large limits, you're probably running into a ulimit.

`ulimit -a` as the target user will show you that user's maximum file size.  It's probably set to the default,

```
fsize = 2097151
```

which is 2097151 x 512byte blocks, which is 1GB.

You can change the ulimits for a specific user by using the `chuser` command.

In your update, you have included what looks like the output of `ulimit -a` for the `root` user, but it's not clear given you don't show us which user you're running it as.  We would need to see the output for the target user (i.e. the user running the sftp if they are pulling files from a remote system, or the user of the target sftp if you are pushing files to a remote system).

Comment: Not enough though - see my comment above.  Also, you need to be a little careful, your question was 'how to find the sftp limit', maybe you should reword to say 'I'm transferring this file and it's failing, why?' because it might be nothing to do with limits unless you have evidence to the contrary (in which case, include it).